# Anything wrong with running Behat Selenium scenarios on multiple terminals?

Tags: php, selenium, behat

All the parallel running libraries that I find are outdated or not stable enough.

What would be the issues in running scenarios in separate terminals with a single Selenium Driver running?

Comment: not too sure what you mean by "terminals" here, but for multi-threading you need one thread per driver per browser.

Comment: I'm starting my tests in command line in command prompt. It seems to work, separate Chromedriver windows are opened but I have to wonder if something can go wrong in the long run.

Comment: it's tricky because you really want a bit of a sleep/pause in between tearing down one driver instance and starting a new one.  (...to wait for browser/driver to cleanup on closing... dev mode drops a file that includes sessionID the driver uses to communicate with the browser.)

Answer (score 0):

Behat uses Selenium (java server) as a mean to launch web browser applications and control them using [WebDriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver) (a special somewhat unified API to control browser). Most modern browsers have WebDriver implemented in them (but with different subset of functionality available).

As far as I remember, to run tests in parallel one would run Selenium server and connection to it as a hub, which then routes all the commands to different browser instances.

All that said, browser instances will probably share same session. Even if not single one, then I guess they might clash at some point. So keep that in mind.

Moreover, if some of your tests changes some basic settings in your SUT system under test (e.g. change user password or number of items in a cart), then it will affect all other tests running in parallel or in future.

Other than that, outdated does not always mean not working, but rather not given recent updates. *If it works, don't touch it*